# Is there a way to tell if --debug or --verbose was passed to PHPUnit in a test?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm doing some overloading to PHPUnit's Selenium extension that uses the CaptureEntirePageScreenshotToString function, and I would like to only print the path to the screenshot as we go only when --verbose or --debug is passed in.

For instance,
`phpunit --debug ./tests`

Then somewhere in my code I have (this is psudo code)

```
if (--debug)
  echo "Screenshot: /path/to/screenshot.png
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no PHPUnit internal API to do this. The configuration object is not accessible through the test cases directly.

You can't use `PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getInstance()` as thats only the wrapper for the xml config.

My suggestion would be to just use:

```
if(in_array('--debug', $_SERVER['argv'], true)) {
     //Insert your debug code here.
}
```

Relevant classes:

- [**`Command Parser`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/Command.php)
- [**`Test Runner`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php)

Comment: Nice! Never thought of that... Good call.

Comment: Thank you very much! 5 years later!!

Comment: I needed this again almost exactly 2 years later.