# Notice: Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT'

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xampp, stdout

I am trying to set up Amazon Aws Php SDK in Xampp.

After installing the SDK, I am trying to download a bucket from Amazon S3, using the following code.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

include_once ('aws/aws-autoloader.php');
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
     'key'    => '__my__key__',
     'secret' => '__secret__key__'
));

$destination = 'downloaded_bucket';
$source_bucket = '__my__bucket__name';
$key_prefix = '';
$options = array('debug'=>true);

$client -> downloadBucket($destination,$source_bucket,$key_prefix,$options);
?>
```

Now on executing this php from my browser, I get the following error.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' in __my__path\Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSyncBuilder.php on line 294
STDOUT
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in __my__path\Aws\S3\Sync\DownloadSyncBuilder.php on line 124
STDOUT
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in __my__path\Aws\S3\Sync\DownloadSyncBuilder.php on line 124
STDOUT
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in __my__path\Aws\S3\Sync\DownloadSyncBuilder.php on line 124
```

The final 3 warnings occur because of the first Notice, because instead of resource, the string 'STDOUT' is passed.

What is the reason for the first notice? 
The code segment for this notice is

```
if ($this->debug) {
            $this->addDebugListener($sync, is_bool($this->debug) ? STDOUT : $this->debug);
        }
```

which is part of the SDK.
And the culprit for the fwrite warning code is the addDebugListener function

```
protected function addDebugListener(AbstractSync $sync, $resource)
    {
       //blah blah
       fwrite($resource, "Downloading {$from} -> {$to}\n");
       //blah blah
    }
```

My PHP version is 5.4.16

Comment: you may need to define STDOUT if its not defined, whats in line 124

Comment: I think there is some other bootstrap file that is not being included that should be..  one that has `define("STDOUT", "php://output");`

Comment: @DevZer0  A fwrite call.  Have updated the question.

Comment: STDOUT is available automatically when running PHP from the command line. Are you running this through the browser?

Answer (score 46):

The problem, in this case, is that the constant `STDOUT` is not defined. It is a constant available when using the command line, so in order to use them in other settings you can do this:

```
if(!defined('STDIN'))  define('STDIN',  fopen('php://stdin',  'rb'));
if(!defined('STDOUT')) define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'wb'));
if(!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'wb'));
```

This will check whether or not the constant has been defined, and if not, define them according to how they are expected to work.

More information about the constants can be found [here in the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

Comment: Can you please improve this answer by explaining what the code do?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

PHP's CLI interface defines `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR`, which are constants that refer to file handles capable of reading from (`STDIN`) or writing to (`STDOUT`, `STDERR`) standard I/O streams.

Because these are only defined by the CLI interface, you can't use them in a web application unless you define them yourself. The three lines above does just that, but only if they're not only defined, making it safe.

In reality a web application probably doesn't need to access them frequently enough to make them constants.

Comment: warning, in FPM context, STDIN is php://input , not php://stdin  , and STDOUT is php://output , not php://stdout (but i think STDERR is still php://stderr )

Comment: @hanshenrik, No, unfortunately, I've just got here because STDERR is undefined in my FPM setup. Can anybody please tell why? ("web application probably doesn't need to access them frequently" that's true, but I'm not quite sure disabling by default every infrequently used feature is a good idea. :) )

Comment: @Sz. if you're looking for the raw http request body, then it's in `php://input`, what do you want from STDIN anyway?

Comment: This code is a fallback for STDOUT, STDIN, STDERR, if they are not defined. (answer to A.L)

Comment: I ended up using `$out=fopen('php://output', 'wb');` because I wanted to fwrite to a user Browser query. Stdin is probably only relevant when PHP is called on a command line.

Answer (score -5):

You should add, in your own code, something like :

```
define("STDOUT", fopen('log.txt', 'w'));
```

Information about files transfered will be logged into the file 'log.txt'.