# Zend Framework 2 project relative paths in PHPUnit + PHPStorm

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm attempting to execute my PHPUnit test cases within PHPStorm.

I already added the composer.phar at the root of the project, and tied it into my PHPStorm configuration.

Now I right click on the `phpunit.xml.dist` and select run..

The module leverages a Logger module I wrote with the following line

`// Error occurred, begin a logfile
        $logger = new Logger();
        $writer = new Stream('data/logs/services-api.log');
        $logger->addWriter($writer);s`

This works fine while running on Apache, NGinx, etc...

but in PHPunit it seems to not go where I'm expecting.

```

```
Zend\Log\Exception\RuntimeException : "data/logs/services-api.log" cannot be opened with mode "a"
#0 ~ZendProject/module/Common/src/Common/Listeners/ApiErrorListener.php(31): Zend\Log\Writer\Stream->__construct('data/logs/servi...')
#1 [internal function]: Common\Listeners\ApiErrorListener::onRender(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
```

```

I know the data\logs folder is writeable because this code works fine in ZendFramework on Apache... I'm guessing I need to modify my Bootstrap.php somehow?

How can I debug this path, and more importantly refactor my PATH(s) properly for production AND PHPUnit calls?

**Edit** : I am starting to ouput my current working directory thanks to this tip

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493389/389976

```
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->expectOutputString('');
        print_r("Current Working Directory = " . getcwd());
        print "";
     ...
    }
```

Giving me some output ...

```
 Current Working Directory = ~ZendProject/module/ActivityWall/test
```

How do I properly modify the CWD so that PHPunit can log properly?  I'm guessing in BootStrap.php but...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to write to the main logfile, I've decided to allow the PHPUnit test it's own `test/data/logs/services-api.log`

**Advantage** : This isolates log files and allows me to see with some assurance what is coming from where..

**Disadvantage** : adds another thing I have to `tail -f`