# "Emulate" PhpUnit, running test manually

Tags: php, unit-testing

Im developing by unit testing, but while testing, I often need to check variables, dump them, etc. That is impossible right now, since PhpUnit runs in console. I want to run it on web-interface. Is there a way? All I do right now is, first run `setUpBeforeClass()` and then `setup()` before each test method.

Comment: Why would you want to `dump` in tests? How are you "developing by unit testing"? Unit tests are for testing what you have / or going to develop.

Comment: I mean, just use dumping temporarly.

Comment: Yes but why? What does "developing by unit testing" mean? What are you doing that you need to dump data?

Comment: for example, lets test an INSERT command. Lets insert it and query this record. But oh, I dont know the field, so lets var_dump them how they look alike

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPUnit: CLI output during test debugging possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493102/phpunit-cli-output-during-test-debugging-possible)